# Libre Office - Convert Japanese file incorrectly

Tags: libreoffice, pdf, convert

I am using the shell conversion method of Libre Office:

```
soffice --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export --outdir ./ ./file.docx
```

I am converting docx files to pdf.

I have a docx file in Japanese which Libre Office converts correctly on my machine but **on Google cloud virtual machine it isn't converted correctly**.

The conversion is changing every Japanese letter to the first letter in the file - Example Text:

> > 1
>
> 第第第  第第
>
> 第第第  第   第
>
> 1.1 第第第第
>
> 第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第
>   第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第
>   第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第第

Libre office is updated to the latest(5.3.3.2) and working on the same Ubuntu version on both(16.04).

What can be the problem here?